# Let X : Ω → R be a random variable on a probability space that is normally distributed.

Tags: probability, limits, random-variables, normal-distribution

> Let $X:\Omega\mapsto \Bbb R$ be a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\Bbb P)$ that is distributed according tothe normal distribution with mean $\mu\in\Bbb R$ and variance $\sigma^2>0$.  Let $M>0$ and show that $$\lim_{c\to\infty}\Bbb P(\{\lvert X\rvert>c\})e^{Mc}=0$$

This is the full question above.

I'm quite stuck on this question so I was just hoping for some hints on how to go about proving the limit at the bottom of the question.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The limit is of indeterminant form.  Have you tried l'Hopital's rule?

Answer (score 1):

if you first consider a standard normal variable, you could use $0 \le e^{Mc}\int_c^\infty e^{-x^2/2}dx \le e^{Mc} \int_c^\infty \frac{x}{c} e^{-x^2/2}dx$ which can be integrated easily using the substitution $u = x^2$.

Comment: My idea was ment for positive $c$ (as it will tend to $\infty$), that $x \ge c$ since $c$ is the lower integral variable, so we have $x / c \ge 1$

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.